# The project file could not be loaded. Could not find a part of the path

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

I am developing a ASP.NET website in visual studio 2015. I am trying to install one NuGet package but getting `The project file could not be loaded. Could not find a part of the path` exception. I tried to delete the .suo file but not helped.
What's wrong with my project and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Opened the project in Visual Studio 2019 and able to install the package successfully.